# SharePoint anonymous access

Tags: authentication

I have several sites that have anonymous access enabled for external users. I would like to collect data from internal users that access the sites (i.e. username) but that is not collected unless the user "signs in" when visiting the site. Is there a way to automatically sign a user in even though anonymous access is enabled?